# Install http ssl module for Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nginx, openssl

Hello I need some advice for add module for existing Nginx installation.

I need to add `http_ssl_module` to my server.

Here is what I got after using `nginx -V`

`nginx version: nginx/1.9.9`

`built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)`

`configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-mail --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic'`

What should I do to add this module to my server?
I tried to use `./configure --with--http_ssl_module` command but its says there is no such file or directory.

Thanks for any advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think you need to install a more complete version of nginx (there are various builds like "light" and "full), or build from source including the module you need.